# elementor plugin генеалогическое древо

Tags: javascript, html, css, плагин, elementor

Где можно найти (сайты, форумы; кроме офф сайта) плагины виджеты для работы в elemеntor'е
Или же нормально рабочий плагин подскажите по созданию генеалогического древа

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rha8sg79/ типа такого ?

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mell0kat/5cb91a2048384560dfa8f041fd9a0295 или это

Comment: @MaximLensky что-то похожее но более функциональнее, то бишь поисковик добавление фото и смотреть каждого отдельно его информацию